# Idiot-proofing Excel fields of MAC Addresses and Phone Numbers

Tags: regex, excel, mac-address

I was tasked with making an Excel spreadsheet where MAC addresses and directory numbers would be added later. The task, though, was to idiot-proof it somehow.

That is, for the MAC addresses:

- Only allow the characters `0` - `9` and `a` - `f`
- Must have 12 characters

and for the directory number
 - 10 digits

If any of these criteria fail, display an error.

I've been trying to play with regex and data validation, and I'm just not having any luck. I've been googling any combination of `excel mac address regex limiting` as terms and not  gotten much further.

**TL;DR** I need to check whether entered phone numbers and MAC addresses are properly formatted when entered in a cell.

Comment: Probably better to write a Worksheet_Change where you can completely customize the data validation. Hex2Dec might help as it would error if bad mac was input.

Comment: Be sure to consider *all* possible ways the users will input data.  To quote Douglas Adams, "A common mistake that people make when trying to design something completely foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete fools."

Comment: @BruceWayne - ... and whenever someone builds something idiot-proof, the world just builds a better idiot.

Answer (score 0):

For the MAC address: `[0-9a-f]{12}`
For the directory number: `\d{10}`

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/559450/588764) by [allquixotic](https://superuser.com/users/144607/allquixotic) for how to use these patterns in Excel, but substitute the correct regex.

As the comments mentioned though, idiot proof is going to be an unreachable goal.